# Looking to see why cards are banned

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking to see why certain cards are banned in certain formats. It doesn't seem to make sense. The specific cards I'm looking for are:

- [Jace, Memory Adept](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Memory%20Adept) (ok, sort of makes sense)
- [Daggerdrome Imp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daggerdrome%20Imp)
- [Dimir Aqueduct](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dimir%20Aqueduct)
- [Mind Grind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mind%20Grind)
- [Pilfered Plans](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pilfered%20Plans)

Can anyone tell me where I can get these rulings at?

tappedout.net says that my deck is not standard legal because of these cards.

Comment: For future reference, you can link to cards with the syntax `[mtg:Card Name]`

Comment: Jace Memory Adept isn't banned in any format. Are you thinking of Jace the MindSculptor, aka one of the most powerful cards in Magic history? Giving this -1 until the question is clarified.

Comment: According to Gatherer, **none** of those cards are banned in any format

Comment: Oh... Sorry, I was going based off of tappedout.net. It said these cards were banned and that didnt make any sense to me. Here is the deck I'm referring to: http://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/black-n-blue-discard-deck/ If you look, it says its illegal due to the cards I listed.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of formats?  Because this all hinges on knowing what it means that your deck is "Standard" format.

Comment: I guess I dont. I'll google that

Comment: @Sugitime This isn't banning, this is format rotation. The basic information you're looking for is here: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15591/how-often-does-the-standard-set-change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For format restrictions and banned lists, see the following:

http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/formats

http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/bannedrestricted

None of the cards you listed are on a banned list, they just aren't legal in "Standard", which is a format that only includes cards printed in the last two years